# Error making pyplot Slider: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm attempting to use matplotlib to plot table from a dataframe. The table shows perfectly, but it has too many rows to show all at once. I'm trying to use a matplotlib Slider as a vertical scrollbar but I keep getting an error that I don't understand when I try to create the Slider and assign it to a variable. Heres the error:

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'

If anyone could help me solve this I'd really appreciate it. I've been stuck on this for two days and I feel like it's definitely something simple I'm just missing cause I've been working on the same code for too long. Also please let me know if you need any more information.

And just so I'm being upfront, this code is for a homework assignment. **However**, the assignment is about performing Agglomerative Clustering, not how to plot tables with scroll bars. You can rest easy knowing you're not just giving me answers to an assignment. I just need this extra tool to help understand my results.

My Code:

```
def create_table():
    n= input.get()
    print(n)
    model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=n, affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')
    predictions = model.fit_predict(df)
    print(df)
    dfArray = df.to_numpy(copy=True)
    predTable = np.full((len(predictions),9),0.1)

    # prints each row of data with its designated cluster
    for x in range(len(predictions)):
        predTable[x][0] = predictions[x]
        for y in range(0,8):
            #print(dfArray[x][y])
            predTable[x][y+1] = dfArray[x][y]
            print(dfArray[x][y])
            print(predTable[x][y+1])
    print(predTable)

    predTableDF = pd.DataFrame(predTable)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.axis('tight')
    tableObject = ax.table(cellText=predTableDF.values,loc='center')
    fig.tight_layout()

    # Slider code
    startScrollVal = 1
    axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'

    axScroll = plt.axis([0.1, 0.25, 0.0225, 0.63])

    ###getting error here###
    slidebar = Slider(axScroll,'label',1,100,valinit=startScrollVal,orientation='vertical')

    def update(val):
        height = slidebar.val
        tableObject.set_xdata(height/len(tableObject))
        fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    slider.on_changed(update) 
    plt.show()
```

Heres the stack trace:

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'
Stack trace:
 >  File "C:\Users\owner\source\repos\CIS362HW4\CIS362HW4\CIS362HW4.py", line 92, in create_table (Current frame)
 >    slidebar = Slider(axScroll,'label',1,100,valinit=startScrollVal,orientation='vertical')
 >  File "C:\Users\owner\source\repos\CIS362HW4\CIS362HW4\CIS362HW4.py", line 176, in <module>
 >    top.mainloop()
Loaded 'matplotlib.widgets'
Loaded '__main__'
Loaded 'tkinter'
Loaded 'runpy'
```

Comment: I think the previous line of code should contain `.axes()`, rather than `.axis()` - those are rather different methods.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you so much! That fixed the error. I knew it had to be something simple I was overlooking.